# Where can I find and install the mingw-w64 packages for centos-7?

Tags: centos, cross-compilation, mingw

Trying to get cross compiling working on centos7.  (I have jenkins running in that environment.)  There is a lot of out of date documentation on the web for mingw.  Apparently there was an answer **[here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294989/where-can-i-find-and-install-the-mingw-w64-packages-for-centos-7)** but is gone.  The cross compilation steps are discussed **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033997/how-to-compile-for-windows-on-linux-with-gcc-g)**.  I can do a **sudo yum groupinstall -y packagename**, but nothing I try works (MinGW-64 mingw-64 mingw64, MinGW64, or MinGW cross-compiler) as I have seen in various posts and forums.  I also tried downloading the source but had no luck with that also as various pre-requsites are missing, and when I try and obtain them they don't exist or are the wrong version.

Comment: Have you tried installing using the [EPEL repositories](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL)?

Comment: That's a good resource I was unaware of.  I found discussion groups and some good documentation there.  Thanks.  I wonder why Google could not point it out?

Comment: @ggb667 Because as of lately google has completely abandoned search for information in favour of search for advertising.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the [EPEL repo installed](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) you can install `mingw-w64` with:

```
yum install mingw64-gcc
```

Comment: As of 2020-02-17 15:24:00 UTC mingw can no longer be found in the Centos 7 EPEL Repository
See https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1807975 and https://pagure.io/fesco/issue/2333 for more information on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Finally located a compiled binary (good enough for my purposes) that will work.  Here is the 64 bit binary for linux (prebuilt, just DL, and unpack it and upload the tar to the box).  You will need to create an /opt/mingw64 directory and untar the file in that directory (sudo tar -xvf ~/mingw-w64-bin_x86_64-linux_20131228.tar) for ex.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/files/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Automated%20Builds/
http://www.blogcompiler.com/2010/07/11/compile-for-windows-on-linux/

The compiler will be /opt/mingw64/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc instead of just gcc.  The reason for this is that we should be able to pick the right gcc, even if  there are multiple compilers in the PATH environment.

Comment: works, but note that this is an old version with so many bugs and issues that the development team has decided to cancel maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for mingw64-binutils to support linking EFI binaries, there is another, easier approach.

In Sep 2016 Fedora patched the distro gnu loader in binutils to support i386pep, which is what you need for EFI linking. So what I did is get that source, extract the patch, and apply it to the latest binutils you want to use in C7. I've done this multiple times if you need more help. I also have a working binary package for binutils patched this way. The build is easy and quick, even easier to test.

Here is what you see on C8:

```
 ld -V
GNU ld version 2.30-79.el8
  Supported emulations:
   elf_x86_64
   elf32_x86_64
   elf_i386
   elf_iamcu
   i386linux
   elf_l1om
   elf_k1om
   i386pep   <--- EFI support
```